# Glob fails recursion on networked location?

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I'm attempting to grab the filepaths of a specific type of file (.EIA) recursively from a networked location, using pathlib for the first time.

Attempting to search from top-level looks like this:

```
>>> for path in pathlib.Path('\\\\192.168.40.104').rglob('*.EIA'):
...     print(path)
...
>>>
```

(It prints nothing)

But directing it one level down to a folder I know contains some .EIA files looks like this:

```
>>> for path in pathlib.Path('\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd').rglob('*.EIA'):
...     print(path)
...
\\192.168.40.104\510bd\CLASSIFIED-01-110.EIA
\\192.168.40.104\510bd\CLASSIFIED-02-110.EIA
\\192.168.40.104\510bd\CLASSIFIED-01-110-510C-BD.EIA
\\192.168.40.104\510bd\CLASSIFIED-01-120.EIA
\\192.168.40.104\510bd\CLASSIFIED-02-110.EIA
\\192.168.40.104\510bd\CLASSIFIED-01-70A.EIA
>>>
```

So . . . why is rglob not searching recursively?

EDIT: I've repeated the same issue with glob:

```
>>> glob.glob('\\\\192.168.40.104\\**\\*.EIA',recursive=True)
[]
>>>
```

and of course:

```
>>> glob.glob('\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\*.EIA',recursive=True)
['\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\CLASSIFIED-01-110.EIA', 
'\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\CLASSIFIED-02-110.EIA', 
'\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\CLASSIFIED-01-110-510C-BD.EIA', 
'\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\CLASSIFIED-01-120.EIA', 
'\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\CLASSIFIED-02-110.EIA', 
'\\\\192.168.40.104\\510bd\\CLASSIFIED-01-70A.EIA']
```

Comment: I'm not on a Windows machine right now to be able to test things myself, _but_ the top-level `\\somehost` is special: It's listing shares available on that host. Whereas `\\somehost\someshare` is referring to a specific share, and `\\somehost\someshare\somedir` is referring to a directory on a share on a host.

Comment: Point of that being that the top level is quite distinct from a reference to any directory within an individual share at the implementation level, so it's not hugely surprising to have some differences in behavior bubble up to the application layer. See: law of leaky abstractions, &c.

Comment: So, you would then predict that if I started on the directory layer glob would behave as expected from that point down?

Comment: Share or directory layer should be good, yes.

Comment: I tried this from a lower level on a different network location and it worked. (So thanks!) Unfortunately that doesn't help me with specifically this use-case, because the files of interest are one level down from the top -- there are multiple network locations setup like this.

Comment: Mmm. There are various approaches to going lower-level -- I just filed a bug report against RubySMB within the last week or so and it was promptly handled -- but that doesn't necessarily mean they'll be _easy_.